# Let $e$ be an edge of minimum weight in the connected weighted graph $G$. Every minimum spanning tree of $G$ contains $e$

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $e$ be an edge of minimum weight in the connected weighted graph
>   $G$. Every minimum spanning tree of $G$ contains $e$.

I have been told that this is not true. But I also know this property :
[Must a minimum weight spanning tree for a graph contain the least weight edge of every vertex of the graph?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681816/must-a-minimum-weight-spanning-tree-for-a-graph-contain-the-least-weight-edge-of)

Is it not true because that $e$ is not necessary the only minimum weight edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ contains a cycle of edges *each* of the same minimum weight, then it is not possible for $G$ to have a spanning tree without omitting at least one of those edges.

Otherwise the answer is yes: Let $T$ be a spanning tree of $G$ NOT containing $e$.  Then $T+e$ contains one cycle.  By assumption, there is an edge in the cycle of non-minimum weight.  Remove that edge, and we have a new spanning tree $T'$ of lower weight.